# How to create a link to Telegram profile with user ID - Node.js

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I'm trying to log my data from my bot and I use this script:

```
bot.use((ctx, next) => {
    console.log(ctx.from);
    if(ctx.updateSubTypes[0] == "text") {
    bot.telegram.sendMessage(-4..5, "@" + ctx.from.username + " said: " + ctx.message.text)
    } else {
    bot.telegram.sendMessage(-4..5, "@" + ctx.from.username + " sent a " + ctx.updateSubTypes[0]);
    }
    next();
})
```

This code works well with the usernames, but what if the user doesn't have one.
I would like to know if there is a possibility to have the first_name with a link to the user profile using just the user ID, so I could anytime check the profile of users who are running my bot.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you could use [markdown](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style) to mention an user by ID you could do 
 `[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789)`

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work like this:

```
bot.use((ctx, next) => {
    if(ctx.updateSubTypes[0] == "text") {
    bot.telegram.sendMessage(-4..5, `<a href="tg://user?id=${ctx.from.id}">${ctx.from.first_name}</a> sent : ${ctx.message.text}`, {parse_mode: 'HTML'})
    } else {
    bot.telegram.sendMessage(-4..5, `<a href="tg://user?id=${ctx.from.id}">${ctx.from.first_name}</a> sent a ${ctx.updateSubTypes[0]}`, {parse_mode: 'HTML'})
    }
    next();
})
```

I hope this will help you in case you have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

`ctx.updateSubTypes` is no longer supported after `telegraf 4.0.3`.

But I don't know what is the new alternative for this method?

**Check out =>** [https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/releases/tag/v4.0.0#:~:text=Remove%20ctx.updateSubTypes](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/releases/tag/v4.0.0#:%7E:text=Remove%20ctx.updateSubTypes)